# is it safe to use non ASCII unicode characters like ♺ in web sites?

Tags: unicode

Taking into account web browsers, operating systems, iphone, blackberries, etc

Comment: Define "safe". "Will be shown correctly", or "will not cause any security vulnerabilities", or what do you mean?

Comment: My intention was "be shown correctly". But is it possible that a single character can cause any security vulnerability!?

Comment: Sure, a ' character can be used for SQL injection if you're not sanitising your queries properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While "safe" -- either by correctly setting the encoding when delivering the page or by escaping using `&#xxx;` -- not all users will have fonts that can render these characters. Particularly "dingbat" characters (accented Western text characters are generally supported anywhere).

So as long as you're OK with some (relatively small) percentage of your users seeing a box rather than a glyph, go ahead.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the character and the font(s).  You will need to experiment with the characters you are interested in.

Remember that CSS allows you to apply more than one font to a block of text: if a particular character is not available in your first choice font, but is available in your second choice font, the browser will use the second choice font for that character, even when it can use the first choice font for the rest of the text.

(This does all assume you have set the character encoding correctly.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [WGL4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wgl4). It's list of characters that should be shown correctly on windows machines and I think this means it will be shown correctly on majority of devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you define properly encoding in html headers, then it is generally safe. However some devices might have problem displaying the character, but it really depends on exact character.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe unless you set the proper encoding type of your pages. That's reason why you see various languages of the world in html pages.